# Thank you Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! A book was born

Tags: discussion

I never thought I would, but I did. I published a book :) And it all started here at this Stack Exchange. Thanks to all the questions that I could answer and all the answers to my question.

I have mentioned this site in the book and on my blogs and I hope that more people will visit here, asking even tougher questions now :)

I based the book on what I wanted to do with the Pi, me a non Linux, Microsoft guy :) (Did I just create an oxymoron? LOL) And I tried my best to make a tutorial type book for beginners and people that know something but not much about Linux, like me.

I really wanted to incorporate GPIO, DIY stuff.. But that did not fit the topic. Maybe my next book? Who knows.

[Please visit my blog](http://raspberrypi-pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/raspberry-pi-server-essentials-my-book.html) and if you think it may help somebody you know - they can use the link for discounted prices, in turn I hope this will bring people back here.

Thank you for being awesome!

Comment: I was also approached to write a book on the back of my contributions to SE; it's a great way to make a name. Congratulations!

Comment: Hey, me too! Nice one!

Comment: Good job! As an idea for a future release, try including a tutorial for setting up a Raspberry Pi based Bukkit MC server, that's a fun project I've been working on!

Comment: Thanks guys :) I will look into the Bukkit MC server. Not sure what that is :)

Comment: That is really awesome. Congratulations! Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Neat! A couple of publishers approached me, but I had too heavy a workload with my day job. If only now …

Comment: Best of luck with this! It might be worth re-visiting the opening promo sentence though: "Raspberry Pi makes a good server that facilitates you with eminently achievable to the massively ambitious ideas." - what?

Comment: Its gone into printing. Dammit.. What a quirk on the first page. No idea how I missed that. It was re read like 20zillion times. Possibly skimming memory overflow error..

Comment: I would say a book about GPIO for Pi would be really great since most people have no clue how/what GPIO is/works. Most projects on the official RPI website do not actually show and teach about GPIO. This is probably the reason people tend to lean towards Arduinos, even though RPIs are just as good if not better.